# How to create highlightjs plugin on nuxt3

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, nuxt3, highlight.js

I try to create a plugin in nuxt3 that uses highligh.js and use it on my components. But I can't do it

I make this :

```js
// @/plugins/highlight.js

import 'highlight.js/styles/stackoverflow-light.css'
import hljs from 'highlight.js/lib/core';
import json from 'highlight.js/lib/languages/json';

hljs.registerLanguage('json', json);

import 'highlight.js/styles/vs.css'

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  nuxtApp.vueApp.use(hljs)
})
```

I want to use like this :

```js
// @/components/JSONView.vue
<template>
  <highlightjs
    language="json"
    :code="myCode"
   />
</template>

<script setup>

const code = ref('{ "done": true }')

</script>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the official [Vue plugin](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js#using-with-vuejs) from highlight Js

`npm i @highlightjs/vue-plugin`

`~/plugins/highlight.client.ts`

```js
import hljs from 'highlight.js/lib/core'
import javascript from 'highlight.js/lib/languages/javascript'
import highlightJS from '@highlightjs/vue-plugin'
import 'highlight.js/styles/atom-one-dark.css'

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
    hljs.registerLanguage('javascript', javascript)
    nuxtApp.vueApp.use(highlightJS)
})
```

Component usage

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
const JSONEXample = JSON.stringify({ firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Wick', age: 37 }, null, 3)
</script>
<template>
  <main>
    <ClientOnly>
      <highlightjs
          autodetect
          :code="JSONEXample"
      />
    </ClientOnly>
  </main>
</template>
```

Tested and it works.
[image]

Comment: What is your version of nuxt and vue-plugin ? i got nuxt 3.7 and vue-plugin 2.1.0 but i got a error : `Vue is not defined at ./node_modules/@highlightjs/vue-plugin/dist/highlightjs-vue.min.js:1:1171 `

Comment: We have the same version of the plugin and the Nuxt. Did you try to copy the code?

Comment: well i got the same code, on my project this doesn't work but on a fresh install that work ... i tried to reinstall dependencies, .nuxt, the project but i got the same problem x)

Comment: I guess it's safe to say that the issue might be a conflict with your other codes. Do you have a repo? so we can to investigate deeper, if that is okay with you.

Comment: yep the code is open-source, https://github.com/ezpaarse-project/ezunpaywall/blob/nuxt3. You can only run the frontend with node at src/frontend2 with command `npm run dev`. For my part, I'm going to try to start from a nuxt3 base with highlightjs, adding my other plugins one by one to see if there are any conflicts.

Comment: What pages/component you are using the highlight.js? Also, try prefixing the .client in your plugin file. As well as using the ClientOnly component of Nuxt

Comment: Yep, I had found it but you were quicker than me, thx for the help. I will add a note on this point

Answer (score 0):

An additional note

If you use nuxt3 in SSR, your highlight.js plugin must contain the word `client`, like `highlight.client.js` and not `highlight.js`.

Nuxt 3 relies on a SSR package that is not compatible with ESM modules.

By using `.client` in the name of plugin, the module is imported only on the browser side and in ESM module.